# Passing 3 parameters from angularjs $resource to C# Web API Controller Post method, one of the parameters returns null

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have been trying to pass 3 parameters into my post method from angularjs to my C# web api controller. The information is being passed to the angularjs service correctly. But Have tried many combinations on the client and server side post method to receive multiple parameters but the closest I have come is 2/3.

here is my code.

SERVER SIDE CONTROLLER:

// POST api/values

```
    [HttpPost("{id}")]

    public IActionResult Post(int id, string userId, [FromBody]Post post)
    {
        if(post.Id == 0)
        {

            _repo.AddPost(id, userId, post);
        }
        else
        {
            _repo.UpdatePost(post);
        }
        return Ok(post);
    }
```

CLIENT SIDE SERVICE: 
namespace MyApp.Services {

```
export class PostsService {
    private postsResource;

    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        this.postsResource = this.$resource("/api/posts/:id");
    }

    getPost(id) {
        return this.postsResource.get({ id: id });
    }


    savePost(id, userId, postToSave) {
        return this.postsResource.save({ id: id }, { userId: userId }, postToSave).$promise;
    }

    deletePost(id) {
        return this.postsResource.delete({ id: id }).$promise;
    }
}

angular.module("MyApp").service("postsService", PostsService);
```

}

Any tips or suggestions? Much appreciated!

Comment: What if you specify the `[FromUri]` attribute on the `userId` argument in the controller action?

Comment: I tried the 5 [From---] options on the userId, however there wasn't a [FromUri]. I tried inputting that and bringing in a using statement but it didn't have one. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: The `FromUriAttribute` for web api is in the `System.Web.Http` namespace

Comment: Just saw this message, thanks for the reply! I went to test that and it turns out that is not supported in .NET Core yet. So I worked around it for now by bringing back the parent id and userId as one parameter and doing some string manipulation and parsing and got it to work. But I will be checking back when the next release candidate comes out for core to see if that works. Thanks for the added knowledge and help. Much appreciated!